# Does essential matrix differ from extrinsic matrix? Why does essential matrix have only 5 degrees of freedom?

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

1. To my understanding essential matrix maps two different 3-d coordinate systems of two cameras. Similar mapping is doen by extrinsic matrix. It maps world cordinate system to camera cordinate system. So how do they differ in terms of mapping?
2. If they do not differ  why are 6 parameters required for extrinsic matrix and only 5 parameters for essential matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Extrinsic matrix is calculated during calibration, where the calibration object has known dimensions, making determination of the camera's pose in space possible (with respect to the object).  This gives 3 degrees of freedom for position, and 3 for orientation.

Essential matrix relates two images, but without knowledge of sizes of objects in the image.  This reduces one degree of freedom due to the fact that scale is not known.  If you know the magnitude of the translation between the two camera poses, you can regain the scale information, which is what is done in stereo vision.

Answer (score 0):

The two matrices have different roles.
**The extrinsic matrix** maps from the "world" coordinate system to the camera coordinate system. Usually, when calculating disparity image, we will choose the "world" coordinate system as one of the cameras coordinate system, but it is not an obligation. For example, if you have points in 3D (points that you know their exact position in the space) you will compute the extrinsic matrix for each of the cameras. The extrinsic matrix equation is:
[image]

**The essential matrix** is a constraint on points in both of the cameras system, the constraint is:
[image]

Now, to answer your questions:

1. Extrinsic matrix is a **mapping** of a **3D point** in one coordinate system to another, when essential matrix is a **constraint** on a location of a point **on camera sensor plane** given the poses of the cameras and the point seen in the other camera sensor plane.
2. In general case, the essential matrix has **six** degrees of freedom, it encodes the **translation** and the **rotation** of one camera from the other (3 degrees of freedom for each).